# How do I access the encrypted credentials in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have this code in the controller

```rb
def index
  puts Rails.application.credentials.admin_email
  if (current_admin && current_admin.email == Rails.application.credentials.admin_email)
    #do this
  else
    #do that
  end
end
```

The else branch always happens. I believe this is because I am not getting the string from the encrypted file back, as the puts line never prints anything.

When I type `Rails.application.credentials.admin_email` in the rails console, I get the correct response, `"xxx@xxx.com"`

My `config/credentials.yml.enc` file looks like the following:

```
admin_email: xxx@xxx.com
```

I have also tried changing the `config/credentials.yml.enc` file to be:

```
development:
  admin_email: xxx@xxx.com
```

And have changed the code to be

```rb
puts Rails.application.credentials[:admin_email]
if (current_admin && current_admin.email == Rails.application.credentials[:admin_email]
```

Then in the rails console I get the correct `xxx@xxx.com` using

```rb
Rails.application.credentials[:development][:admin_email]
```

, but still nothing shows up from the development code when running `rails s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you might have a typo/ copy paste error.

If you still have the credentials file in this format:

```
development:
  admin_email: xxx@xxx.com
```

Then you should be accessing it with

```
Rails.application.credentials.development[:admin_email]
```

In your question though under "And have changed the code to be"  you still have the old version:

```
puts Rails.application.credentials[:admin_email]
if (current_admin && current_admin.email == Rails.application.credentials[:admin_email]
```

This should be:

```
puts Rails.application.credentials.development[:admin_email]
if (current_admin && current_admin.email == Rails.application.credentials.development[:admin_email]
```

Comment: @flobacca Yup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to get environment specific credentials and that's why you got the credentials by using below code:-

```
Rails.application.credentials.admin_email
```

for more please check here
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31349

OR 
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30067

Comment: Rails.application.credentials.admin_email is what I am using in my code. The puts method prints nothing. Using this in the rails console does print the correct token.